# OpenGL/GLEW: Unresolved external _glewInit

Tags: c++, opengl, unresolved-external, glew

I cannot get GLEW to link correctly with my program.

I have the path correct in my project (I've triple checked), I have tried building from scratch, using the x86 libs (all 4 - the -s, -mxs, etc) AND the x64 libs.

I have tried using the #pragma directive instead of configuring my project in properties.

I am trying to get it as a static lib so no DLLs will be necessary.

I also have GLEW_STATIC defined, as the build instructions advise.

Error message:

> OGLInit.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _glewInit@0
>   referenced in function "bool __stdcall vexal::OGLStartup(void)"
>   (?OGLStartup@vexal@@YG_NXZ)

I've even used dumpbin to check that initGlew is there. It is, and it is external.

I've also verified it's found the lib.

> Searching
>   C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Vexal2\vexal\vc9_x86\lib\Debug\GLEW.lib:

I've run out of ideas here. Any help?

Comment: Are you 100% sure you're linking to the static glew library and not the 'import' library (that actually just acts as a proxy to the dll)?

Comment: Yep. I rebuilt it using the glew_static project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the calling convention. I changed the calling convention settings to `__stdcall` instead of `__cdecl`, changed `_glfwTerminate_atexit( void )` to __cdecl in the GLFW code I had, and then built.

Fixed!

Answer (score 1):

> Yep. I rebuilt it using the glew_static project.

Just because you built that project doesn't mean you're *linking* to it.

> C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Vexal2\vexal\vc9_x86\lib\Debug\GLEW.lib

That is not the static GLEW library. That is the import library for the DLL version of GLEW. The static GLEW library is called `GLEW32s.lib`. Link to that.

Comment: Alright, made those libraries. Added the DLL not only to the solution dir, but to the project dir and the Debug dir as well. Still getting the same error.

Comment: You're supposed to *not* be linking to the DLL. You're building the *static* GLEW, not the DLL version. If you want to use GLEW as a DLL, you have to take out your `GLEW_STATIC` definition.

Comment: That's what I've been doing _-_ I defined GLEW_STATIC in the project and built, which yielded GLEW.lib (which is what I told it to make).